# LVM while mdadm is creating a RAID6

Tags: linux, partitioning, raid, software-raid

So earlier today I was setting up a new server and creating a RAID6 array with mdadm. I then decided to create a physical and logical volume with LVM while it was running and throw on ext4. So before I started with LVM the estimated resync time from /proc/mdstat was 300 minutes, and after I messed with the filesystem and stuff it's at 4,000 minutes. Should I be alarmed? Shooould I restart it from scratch and let mdadm finish before throwing LVM on?

This is on Debian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't restart.  The initial RAID construction is pretty disk intensive since it has to read the data off some of the drives, compute checksums, and write those checksums to the other drives.

When you created the LVM you were competing for IO bandwidth with the resync.  There probably were not many blocks involved in just the LVM work.  However when you synthesized the filesystem there was rather more IO as it initialized inode tables and superblocks.

Once the filesystem has been created, the RAID construction will go back to monopolizing the IO and the sync rate reported by cat /proc/mdstat will go back up.

I would, however, minimize the amount of IO I do that involves those disks during the process so that it can devote all its head seeks to the RAID reconstruction.  Don't start ripping your DVDs to that new LV just yet.

IO contention might be unavoidable if you have important work that uses those disks (like recording the latest episode of PBS Newshour over ATSC).  It shouldn't cause corruption, it will just slow things down.